# Structuring a solution

Tags: winforms, unit-testing, c#-4.0

Im trying to structure my winforms project in accordance with the suggested layout in this blog post [Code Rant.](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/how-to-structure-visual-studio.html)

originally, i had managed to have multiple solution files, dont know how i managed it. Anyway ive heard there should only be one. Also been told to have one class per file (i sometimes had 2 or 3 in one class file.)

What im having problems understanding is what each of these should be. In the link he has 3 project for that solution.

**[QUESTION]** should i do the following: solution(right click)->Add->New Project->Winform Application, and then just delete out the form1.cs and Program.cs?

Ive tried solution(right click)->Add->Solution Folder but this doesnt give the same layout as he has.

**[QUESTION]** When should i use a class library in his example? Originally i had all my classes stored in folders in a class library.

**[QUESTION]** Where should my unit testing code go?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all his projects have `ClassLibrary` type, because there is no references to `System.Windows.Form.dll`. To create same solution structure, just add three `ClassLibrary` projects to your solution.
Your unit testing should go to separate projects (also of type `ClassLibrary`).

Answer (score 1):

Just a small note that if you stick to the MSTest unit testing framework, you'll have to use the special project type. I don't remember the exact name, something like Unit Testing Project. Other frameworks like NUnit, mbUnit, etc. are fine with plain Class Library projects.

Comment: Cheers for the heads up. Im using NUnit so should be fine :)